# using data from java classes and methods

Tags: java, android

i have an entry level question:

if there is external java class let's say 'Class1' inside this class there is a method called 'method1' inside this method there is Override method 'onResponse' inside this method two variables is being set 'a' and 'b'.

in the android mainActivity i called the method from the class like this:

```
Class1.method1();
```

after calling the method how i can retrieve these variables to be used in mainActivity...

thanks..

```
public abstract class Class1 extends Context {

final Context mcontext;


public static void method1(final Context mcontext, final String x){


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, constants.URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONObject userDetails = parentObject.getJSONObject("data");

                        //read attributes
                        String a = userDetails.getString("a");
                        String b = userDetails.getString("b");



                    } catch (JSONException e) {


                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(mcontext, error.getMessage() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("x", x);
            return params;
        }
    };

    requestHandler.getInstance(mcontext).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: Could we please see the code associated with Class1/Method1

Comment: @Wamadahama please see the full code above

Comment: There's no way you could get variables a and b from the MainActivity because they're part of the Method1 scope

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a wrapper class for `a` and `b`

```
public class Details {
    public string a;
    public string b; 
}
```

and then read/return it in the method1

```
public abstract class Class1 extends Context {

final Context mcontext;


public static Details method1(final Context mcontext, final String x){

    Details data = new Details;


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, constants.URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONObject userDetails = parentObject.getJSONObject("data");

                        //read attributes
                         data.a = userDetails.getString("a");
                         data.b = userDetails.getString("b");



                    } catch (JSONException e) {


                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(mcontext, error.getMessage() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("x", x);
            return params;
        }
    };


    requestHandler.getInstance(mcontext).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

    return data; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return more than one value you should use Android ways called Intent
but if you insist
you can use Array or ArrayList return type for the inner inner method

```
  class Class1{
     public static ArrayList<Object> method1(){
         return onResponse();
}
public static ArrayList<Object> onResponse(){
return arrayList<Object>;
```

} 
    }

but still i see no reason to not use Intent